# How to use Bit Miracle LibTiff.Net to write the image to a MemoryStream

Tags: tiff, libtiff.net

I received a Image compressed using **CCITTFaxDecode**. So I used LibTiff.Net from Bit Miracle to be able to convert the image to any format.

I need to write the decompressed image to a `MemoryStream`. I used a code example from another thread and  I was able to use this code

```
using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic;
...   

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
TiffStream stm = new TiffStream();

Tiff tiff = Tiff.ClientOpen("","w",ms,stm);
tiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, UInt32.Parse(pd.Get(PdfName.WIDTH).ToString()));
tiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, UInt32.Parse(pd.Get(PdfName.HEIGHT).ToString()));
tiff.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.CCITTFAX4);
tiff.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, UInt32.Parse(pd.Get(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT).ToString()));      
tiff.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);       
tiff.WriteRawStrip(0, raw, raw.Length);  
MemoryStream newStream =   (MemoryStream)tiff.Clientdata();

tiff.Close();
```

The problem I'm having is that the `MemoryStream` byte array is not a valid image.

I used `System.Drawing.Image` class to load this `newStream` memory stream, but there are some null values in the byte array.

If I use the `Open` constructor to write the image to disk it works fine.

I would like to know if somebody knows why the `MemoryStream` fails to store the decompressed image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

`Tiff` object closes and disposes stream after call to `Close` method.

So, you probably should change

```
MemoryStream newStream = (MemoryStream)tiff.Clientdata();
```

to

```
MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
```

if you need to use data later.

Another approach is to NOT call `Tiff.Close` until you are done with the memory stream. this approach has some drawbacks, though.